# Regex to Isolate Variable String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a fairly large text file from which I need to extrapolate a string in PHP. The file in question can be accessed [here](http://pkazz.com/debt/data.txt). What I need taken out is the first column of the `Total Public Debt Outstanding` line. It will vary from day to day, that is where I need help. The `Total Public Debt Outstanding` line will always be there, how do I get `preg_match` to match the text immediately following it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it, albeit not very elegant.

```
$data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
preg_match('/Total\s+Public\s+Debt\s+Outstanding\s+(\S+)/', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```